# Who's the killer?

Tags: logical-deduction

When the elevator man saw Mr. Kelley, Mr. Kelley was bleeding slightly, but he did not seem too badly hurt.

Mr. Kelley had destroyed Mr. Jones’ business by stealing all of his customers.

The incident occurred in an area where there had been many crimes.

Mr. Kelley’s body was found in the park.

The elevator man went off duty at 12:30 a.m.

Police were unable to locate Mr. Scott after the murder.

Miss Smith said that the police don’t care about the spread of illegal drugs.

The elevator man said that Miss Smith was in the lobby of the apartment building when he went off duty.

Miss Smith said that nobody left the apartment building between 12:25 a.m. and 12:45 a.m.

An empty crack vial was found outside the apartment house.

The elevator operator reported to police that he saw Mr. Kelley at 12:15a.m.

A knife with Mr. Kelley’s blood on it was found in Miss Smith’s yard.

The elevator man saw Mr. Kelley’s wife go to Mr. Scott’s apartment at
11:30 p.m. Mr. Kelley’s body was found at 1:30 a.m.

When he was discovered dead, Mr. Kelley had a bullet hole in his thigh and a knife wound in his back.

Only one bullet had been fired from Mr. Jones’ gun.

The knife found in Miss Smith’s yard had Mr. Scott’s fingerprints on it.

Mr. Jones said private citizens have the right to keep handguns.

The elevator operator said that Mr. Kelley’s wife frequently left the building with Mr. Scott.

The elevator man saw Mr. Kelley go to Mr. Scott’s room at 12:25 a.m.

When police tried to locate Mr. Jones after the murder, they discovered that he had disappeared.

Mr. Jones had told Mr. Kelley that he was going to kill him.

Mr. Kelley’s bloodstains were found on the carpet in the hall outside Mr. Jones’ apartment.

The elevator man was twice convicted for DWI.

Mr. Jones shot at an intruder in his apartment building at 12:00midnight.

It was obvious from the condition of Mr. Kelley’s body that it has been dragged a long distance.

Miss Smith saw Mr. Kelly go to Mr. Jones apartment building at 11:55p.m.

Miss Smith often followed Mr. Kelley.

Mr. Kelley’s bloodstains were found in Mr. Scott’s car.

The bullet taken from Mr. Kelley’s thigh matched the gun owned by Mr. Jones.

Mr. Kelley had been dead for one hour when his body was found, according to a medical expert working with police.

Comment: This seems to have originated in educational material from the 1980s: [Sleuth+Proof=Truth, a formula for mystery, by Lois Eaton](https://files.eric.ed.gov/fulltext/ED191047.pdf#page44)

Answer (score 2):

Very nice whodunnit riddle! I'm going to say that the guilty party is

> **Mr. Scott.** I know Mr. Jones is the immediate suspect, and he obviously *intended* to kill Mr. Kelley at some point, but I don't think he did.

Here's why:

> "Only one bullet had been fired from Mr. Jones’ gun." and "Mr. Jones shot at an intruder in his apartment building at 12:00midnight." and "Miss Smith saw Mr. Kelley go to Mr. Jones apartment building at 11:55p.m." and "The elevator man saw Mr. Kelley go to Mr. Scott’s room at 12:25 a.m."

These indicate that Mr. Jones

> did shoot Mr. Kelly, but only as an intruder, and not to the death. It was his later trip to Mr. Scott's room that killed him, and resulted in Mr. Scott's car having Mr. Kelley's bloodstains, and the knife with Mr. Kelly's blood having Mr. Scott's fingerprints. Thus, I think I can rearrange night and the clues like so:

1. > "Mr. Kelley had destroyed Mr. Jones’ business by stealing all of his customers." and "Mr. Jones had told Mr. Kelley that he was going to kill him." Nice, but irrelevant until the evidence is presented.
2. > "An empty crack vial was found outside the apartment house." and "The incident occurred in an area where there had been many crimes. " and "Miss Smith said that the police don’t care about the spread of illegal drugs." Nice, but irrelevant.
3. > "Miss Smith saw Mr. Kelly go to Mr. Jones apartment building at 11:55p.m." and "Mr. Jones shot at an intruder in his apartment building at 12:00midnight." Mr. Kelley was the intruder that was shot *or* he was hit by a ricochet from when Mr. Jones fired at the unknown intruder. Either way, the one bullet fired at this time did not kill Mr. Kelley, but did injure him.
4. > "The elevator operator reported to police that he saw Mr. Kelley at 12:15 a.m. " and "The elevator man saw Mr. Kelley go to Mr. Scott’s room at 12:25 a.m." and "When the elevator man saw Mr. Kelley, Mr. Kelley was bleeding slightly, but he did not seem too badly hurt." Mr. Kelley was alive when he went to Mr. Scott's.
5. > "A knife with Mr. Kelley’s blood on it was found in Miss Smith’s yard." and "The knife found in Miss Smith’s yard had Mr. Scott’s fingerprints on it." and "Mr. Kelley’s bloodstains were found in Mr. Scott’s car."
6. > I'm on mobile for this part, sorry no copy-paste right now. Since the body was moved and blood matched with Mr. Scott's car and the knife with his fingerprints, we have a #1 suspect and the murder weapon and the body's means of transportation and corroborating eyewitness.  We also have a motive - one of the lines referenced a possible affair with Mrs. Scott and Mr. Kelley.

That's all I have time for right now. Hope that's a good start.